Setting a Custom Format Script for a specific alphanumeric value (ex. FM000-0000)
First, I am a novice at JavaScript, but eager to learn - so suggestions of good books/avenues for teaching myself would be greatly appreciated!
I am trying to build a .pdf form that uses a specific numbering format - MF000-0000 for data-entry in a field. The 'MF' characters are required, do not change, and must be All CAPS; the following 7 digits are variable, separated by a dash, and will be manually entered by the form user as they are provided by a separate group.
I have searched what feels like everywhere for simple instructions on this (what I see as) simple formatting to no avail.
Can someone help?
I have tried simply entering what it should look like:
with double quotes, as: "FM""000""-""0000"
with single and double, as: "FM'000''-''0000'"
with my best guess from reading some of the Google answers, as: let [field name]="FM"000-0000
But not of this worked either...

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do here. If you write, "FM000-0000" or 'FM000-0000', that will work just fine. But presumably what you actually have is some variable you're trying to output into that format? If so, that variable needs to be mentioned somewhere in your code - you can't just write 000 and expect the computer to turn that into some other number. Perhaps you can give a [mre] of what you're actually testing?

Just curious, are those html data-entry fields? If so I wonder if pattern attribute will work

Apologies, yes - FM and '-' are the constants, and '0' needs to represent variable numbers entered by the user.
In Adobe, when you are in the 'Properties' of a field (in this case, a Text Field'), the Format options only offer 'Special' or 'Custom' for this type of entry. So when I entered the Properties of the ADR_Number field, selected Format, and then Custom, it opens a 'JS Edition' window.
I took a good screenshot of it, but I can't figure out had to add it in a comment here...

Additional JavaScript is not required in AcroForms and many viewers may not run such scripting.
Some may not allow forms entry anyway so default values should be preset such as the lower view.
Acrobat allows for inbuilt field validation and in this case simply use :

Number - Only Numbers can be entered. Any Letters or special characters present an error message: see https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/using/form-field-validations.html

If you set the fields as a comb it will restrict and validate the acceptable format in those Acrobat compatible viewers such as Chromium's.
Here is the 123 field as generated with inclusive scripting.
Text3 is the field name, /MaxLen 3 is the "Comb"
What you are seeking is automatically added by Acrobat compatible editors   :
AFNumber_Format\(0, 0, 0, 0, "", true\) and AFNumber_Keystroke\(0, 0, 0, 0, "", true\)
10 0 obj
<</AA<</F<</JS(AFNumber_Format\(0, 0, 0, 0, "", true\))/S/JavaScript>>/K<</JS(AFNumber_Keystroke\(0, 0, 0, 0, "", true\))/S/JavaScript>>>>/AP<</N 17 0 R>>/DA(0 g /Helv 0 Tf)/F 4/Ff 29360128/FT/Tx/M(D:20240521)/MaxLen 3/MK<</BC[0 0 0]>>/P 12 0 R/Rect[64.29523 39.666669 109.29523 61.666669]/Subtype/Widget/T(Text3)/Type/Annot/V(123)>>
endobj


Here is the 4 number field with Automatic Field Range Validation
AFRange_Validate\(true, 0, true, 9999\)
11 0 obj
<</AA<</F<</JS(AFNumber_Format\(0, 1, 0, 0, "", false\))/S/JavaScript>>/K<</JS(AFNumber_Keystroke\(0, 1, 0, 0, "", false\))/S/JavaScript>>/V<</JS(AFRange_Validate\(true, 0, true, 9999\))/S/JavaScript>>>>/AP<</N 18 0 R>>/DA(0 g /Helv 0 Tf)/F 4/Ff 29360128/FT/Tx/M(D:20240521)/MaxLen 4/MK<</BC[0 0 0]>>/P 12 0 R/Q 1/Rect[124.29523 39.666669 184.29523 61.666669]/Subtype/Widget/T(Text4)/Type/Annot/V(1234)>>
endobj




Even the simplest PDF "Forms" reader should reject keys that are non numeric so here we cannot add any Alpha or $ymbol keys.

